# On sylow p-groups in finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> **Problem**:
>   Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\subset G$ a subgroup and $p$ a prime number. Show that:
>
> (i) If $S\subset H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, then there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup $T\subset G$ of $G$ such that $S=T\cap H$.
>
> (ii) If $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $H$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup.
>
> (iii) If $H\subset G$ is normal and $T\subset G$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $T\cap H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

**My ideas:**

(i) Since $S$ is a sylow p-group of $H$ we know that $\operatorname{ord}(H)=p^l*m$ for $l\in\mathbb{N}$ and p,m coprime. And since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ we know that $\operatorname{ord}(G)=p^k*m*q$ for $k\ge l$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$. So $G$ has a sylow p-group $T$ such that $\operatorname{ord}(T)=p^k$. And since $k\ge l$ it follows that $S=T\cap H$.

(ii) Denote this normal sylow p-subgroup as $F$. We know that $\operatorname{ord}(F)=p^k$ for a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $F$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ (since $F$ is normal). Then $F\cap H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (using (i)) and it is still normal in $H$ since $H\subset G$.

(iii) Since $H$ is normal in $G$, $T\cap H$ is still normal in $H$. If we can show that $T\cap H$ is the only subgroup of $H$ of order $\operatorname{ord}(T\cap H)$ we would be done. This is where I'm stuck.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first sentence in your attempt at (iii) is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last sentence in (i) is fishy. It does not follow that $S=T\cap H$. It is perfectly possible that $T\cap H$ is trivial, if you picked the wrong $T$. As an example consider $G=S_4$, $H\cong S_3=$ the subgroup of elements keeping $4$ fixed. If $p=3$ and $S=\langle(123)\rangle$ then you cannot select $T=\langle(124)\rangle$. You must use a stronger version/by-product of Sylow theorem's. Can you tell which? Hint: It deals with the existence of Sylow subgroups containing a given $p$-subgroup.

In (ii) you need to again explain more carefully, why $F\cap H$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$. Part (i) says that any Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ can be written in the form $S=T\cap H$ for **some** Sylow subgroup $T$ of $G$. Why are you allowed to assume that you are allowed to select $T=F$? Hint: You already said it earlier, but I wasn't entirely convinced that you fully appreciated it, because you had misunderstood what (i) says.

Zibadawa Timmy already pointed out the major flaw in your attempt (iii). Continuing with the above example of $G=S_4$. If we let $H=A_4$, then it's normal in $G$,
but if $T=\langle(123)\rangle$, then $T\le H$, but $T$ isn't normal in $H$.
Instead you could (should?) go via the route of the hint to part (i). First pick a Sylow subgroup $S$ of $H$ containing $T\cap H$. Then part (i) tells you that there exists a Sylow subgroup $T'$ of $G$ such that $T'\cap H=S$. But you should be able to show that $|T'\cap H|=|T\cap H|$. How? As 
$$(T\cap H)\subseteq S\subseteq (T'\cap H),$$
what conclusions can you draw?

Comment: ad (i): I think you are hinting at "If $P$ is a sylow p-subgroup of $G$, then $P$ contains a conjugate of every p-subgroup $U$ of $G$". With that we have that $T$ contains every sylow p-subgroup of $U$, in particular $S$, because every conjugate of a sylow p-group is a sylow p-group. Thus $S=T\cap H$.

Comment: Correct. Well done!

Comment: ad (ii): We are allowed to pick $T=F$ since $F$ is the only sylow p-group of $G$ ($F$ is normal).

Comment: ad (iii): Since $T,T'$ are both sylow subgroups of $G$ they are conjugate to each other. Because $H$ is normal it follows that $T\cap H$ and $T'\cap H$ are conjugate aswell, meaning they have the same amount of elements. Thus $S=T\cap H$ is a sylow subgroup in $H$.

Comment: Correct (ii) + (iii) :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!